# How to convert image from assets to file and send to backend using formdata in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular13

How to convert image from assets to file and send to backend using formdata in angular?

I tried passing image file to form data, but it doesnot pass to backend

```
    getImage() {
        return this.httpClient
          .get('assets/images/logos/logo.png', {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          })
          .pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
              return new File([response], 'default.png');
            }),
          );

  }

 createArticle(articleData: IArticleData, thumbnail?: File | string, articleImage?: File | string) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', articleData.title);
    formData.append('author', articleData.author);
    formData.append('articleData', articleData.articleData);
    formData.append('published', JSON.stringify(articleData.published));

    if (thumbnail) {
      formData.append('thumbnail', thumbnail);
    }

    if (articleImage) {
      formData.append('articleImage', articleImage);
    }

    if (!thumbnail) {
      this.getImage().subscribe((response) => {
        formData.append('thumbnail', response);
      });
    }

    return this.httpClient.post<IAPIResponse<IArticleCollection[]>>(`${baseUrl}/article/`, formData);
  }
```

Comment: From your code, I don't see you are sending request to the backend.

Comment: edited the question - Yong Shun

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping both operations in one stream pipe using RxJS's [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) and [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operators, as follows:

```js
createArticle(
  articleData: IArticleData,
  thumbnail?: File | string,
  articleImage?: File | string
): Observable<any> {
  const formData = new FormData();

  //...

  // If there is a thumbnail, just return an Observable with a null value:
  const source$ = !thumbnail ? this.getImage() : of(null);

  return source$.pipe(
    tap((thumbResult) => {
      if (thumbResult) {
        formData.append('thumbnail', thumbResult);
      }
    }),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.httpClient.post<IAPIResponse<IArticleCollection[]>>(
        `${baseUrl}/article/`,
        formData
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: if i have to add default image to articleImage , then how will be the code?

Comment: Please explain more regarding this. And if it’s another question, I think it’s better to create a new question for it.